# What kind of display connector is this?

Tags: connector, i2c, spi, display

I'm looking into using this display for a small project I'm working on, but I'm not positive what kind of connector it has:

http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/2-4inch-transparent-oled-screen-240_1935783651.html?spm=a2700.7724838.2017115.372.40fbe7700UN3sx

What I can't tell is if it's a standard ribbon cable that'll connect with MIPI/DSI interfaces or if it's something totally different. All it says about the display is that it uses an 8bit Parallel Data with MPU (8080-series MPU).

Comment: SPI and I2C are serial, not parallel.

Comment: Ah ok, my bad, I'll fix that part of the info. I'm still in a research and learning progress about this at the moment.

Comment: It says the protocol is 8080 type 8 bit parallel, aka MIPI DBI. The connector is just some arbitrary pin layout.

Comment: So in that case, do most MIPI DSI host controllers, like say on a Raspberry Pi, accept a MIPI DBI input? I've found mixed things on that when researching it a bit. There doesn't seem to be a very clear consensus on that form what I can tell.

Comment: DSI support does not indicate anything about DBI support. However there is a high chance of the opposite because DSI and DBI doesn't overlap much in terms of time frame and market segmentation.

Comment: Where could I find more information about the DBI interface? I'm trying to research it more and figure out if there are any SBC's that have a DBI interface but everything that comes up is only about the DSI interface. Couldn't even find any information about MIPI even having a DBI standard.

Comment: ask the vendor what the controller is, common ones I know are made by ILI, like this ILI9342, datasheet here http://www.ampdisplay.com/documents/pdf/ILI9342_DS_V008_20100331.pdf . In the datasheet you can find the pin config and command set definition.

Comment: If you use a SoC running Linux, look for the Linux driver for 8080 type display. If there isn't then don't use this display. I've used this type of display on OMAP3530/3730 chips and the linux driver is not perfect but usable.

Answer (score 0):

FFC/FPC connectors.  They are used for flex cables (the gold colored cable).  Flex cables and ribbon cables are not the same.  Flex cables are flexible printed circuit board.